# Deselect radio buttons

Tags: ios, swift

In my project I have function which creates many radio buttons. These buttons are in an array. How to deselect other buttons, when I select one?

Part of my code which works with 2 buttons and doesn't work with 4:

```
func pressedBtn(sender:UIButton){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        let lNumberOfCheckboxes = self.chkDay.count
        for(var counter=0; counter<lNumberOfCheckboxes; counter++){
            if self.chkDay[counter].selected == false{
                self.chkDay[counter].selected = true
                println(self.chkDay[counter].tag)
            } else{
                self.chkDay[counter].selected = false
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And how NOT TO DESELECT selected button, when I click on it?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Is the setting of `selected` connected to the UI state of the matching radio button? Why are you using `dispatch_async`?

Comment: dispatch_async is not necessary(forgot to delete=)). Each button has state of `selected`. I have an array of 4 buttons in which 1st button has state `selected = true`. when i click on 2nd button - 1st deselects and 2nd, 3rd and 4th selects.  O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `self.chkDay` is an array of UIButtons, you can use

```
func pressedBtn(sender:UIButton){   
    for( checkBox in self.chkDay){
        if (checkBox == sender) {
            checkBox.selected=true
        } else {
            checkBox.selected=false
        }
    }
}
```